# ubuntu 20.04 not detecting 3rd display

Tags: 20.04, display

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with 2 graphics cards, an AMD Radeon 550 and a nvidia GeForce GT420. I am trying to get 4 displays running at once but only 2 of them will be detected regardless of which card or what port I plug any of them into.

below is the output of `sudo lshw -c video` with 2 displays on the amd and 2 of them on the nvidia:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 420]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:63 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7a00000-f7a3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```